# Restaurar base de datos SQL en SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Hola, hay forma de restaurar una base de datos que se genero en SQL Server 2012 en un SQL Server 2008? Al intentar hacerlo me marca error de conversión. Alguien sabrá si es posible? El error que me sale es el siguiente: la conversión especificada no es válida. (sqlmanagerui)**

Comment: lo que hacía para versiones 2008 es exportar la base de datos a access y luego ese archivo en access lo importaba a la base de datos mssql 2008, lo mismo se puede hacer con excel, pero con access es mucho mejor visualmente.

Comment: Por favor pon el error completo en la pregunta

Comment: Este es el error que me aparece: la conversión especificada no es válida. (sqlmanagerui)

Answer (score 3):

La primera respuesta que puedes buscar en la documentación oficial es **No**. Por razones de compatibilidad, se puede hacer hacia arriba, en al menos, tres versiones.

[image: Res1]

Pero existen algunas posibilidades que en función de la complejidad de la base de datos, puede ser superSencilla, o requerir algún pequeño retoque.

La primera es la utilización de la herramienta de generación de scripts.
Desde Sql Management Studio puedes generar los scripts, ***con datos***

[image: Res2]

**Siguiente**

[image: res3]

**Siguiente**

Hay que entrar en el botón de **Avanzadas**

[image: res4]

Repasa todas las posibilidades, porque son muy interesantes. Ten especial cuidado con la versión para servidor y con los datos a incluir.

Por defecto, y depende de la versión, algunas opciones, como los desencadenadores, permisos, etc, te vienen marcados como false.

[image: Res5]

Cuando lo tengas preparado.

**Aceptar**

Ahora marca guardar como archivo de script y busca una ruta.

[image: Res6]

**Siguiente ....**

Esta opción funciona muy bien.

[Exportar mediante scripts](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/15/exportar-una-base-de-datos-mediante-scripts/)

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente las herramientas naturales de SQL Server para restaurar a versiones anteriores no son tan directas, o al menos es lo que he visto.

**La razón de por qué no lo hace**, desde mi punto de vista, es debido a que internamente **existen procedimientos almacenados que no son compatibles o incluso podría existir funciones o funcionalidades en la nueva versión que no existen en la anterior** y que al momento de restaurar no sabe que hacer con ellas.

La recomendación sería, suponiendo que cuentas con la estructura de la base de datos en el 2008, realizar un link desde el 2008 a un servidor 2012 y pasas las tablas una a una.

Obviamente hay que tomar en cuenta las dependencias entre tablas por lo que la secuencia de carga es importante, es decir, cargar primeramente las que no dependen de otras tablas y asegurar que cuando cargues cada tabla cuente ya con las tablas a las que tiene relación (constrains).

Suerte!

Comment: Usar JSON o XML es un desperdicio de recursos. Hay formatos más sencillos y eficientes.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).