# Copiar tablas de una Base a Otra(SQL) con los objetos

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas

Necesito copiar varias tablas de una base a otra (sin los datos pero con los objetos de la tabla).

No puedo utilizar el Scripts Table para generar los scripts automáticamente y procedí a copiar las tablas con `SELECT * INTO`, pero me faltaría los objetos de la tabla como los índices y disparadores.

Estoy utilizando SQL 2008 R2.

(Estoy limitado solo a realizar esta tarea con scripts)

Comment: Puedes generar scripts de todas las tablas sin datos. [Generar scripts de la base de datos completa.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/559189/restaurar-base-de-datos-sql-en-sql-2008/559219#559219).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No puedo generar scripts, igual gracias por la respuesta...

Comment: Deberías de ser más explicito con el escenario, y el porque no puedes. No obstante y dado que no aportas detalles suficientes, tienes un procedimiento del sistema, llamado sp_Help_Text que si le pasas como parámetro un objeto como el nombre de cada uno de los triggers te devuelve el texto, por el que está formado. Creo que las constraints, no vas a poder obtenerlas, sin los scripts.

Comment: Cuando intento generar el scrip desde el menu "CREATE TO" me sale el siguinte error.
Script failed for Server '**.**.**.**'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

por eso obte por realizar las copias de las tablas con (SELECT * INTO) pero solo copia la estructura sin los objetos que es lo que estoy necesitando.